# How does one reduce and mutate/change string entries of an array based on common substring patterns?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split, mapreduce

I have an array of string items ...

```
[
  'Mon  : 9:00AM - 7:00PM',
  'Tue  : 9:00AM - 10:00PM',
  'Wed  : Closed',
  'Thu  : 9:00AM - 7:00PM',
  'Fri  : 9:00AM - 7:00PM',
  'Sat  :  Closed',
  'Sun  :  Closed',
]
```

... and I want to achieve a result like the one below ...

```
[
  'Mon: 9:00AM - 7:00PM',
  'Tue: 9:00AM - 10:00PM',
  'Wed: Closed',
  'Thu-Fri: 9:00AM - 7:00PM',
  'Sat-Sun:  Closed',
]
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service and you are expected to do your research and try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried.  Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Firstly one needs to separate the `day` value from the `hours` value part of a single opening hours string.

   - This either can be achieved via [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) and [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) ...

     ```
     function splitOpeningHoursEntry(entry) {
       // e.g.: 'Mon  : 9:00AM - 7:00PM'
       const indexOfColon = entry.indexOf(':'); // e.g. 5

       // entry.substring(0, 5) ... e.g.: 'Mon  '
       const day = entry.substring(0, indexOfColon);
       // entry.substring(6) ... e.g.: ' 9:00AM - 7:00PM'
       const hours = entry.substring(indexOfColon + 1);

       // e.g.: ['Mon', '9:00AM - 7:00PM']
       return [day.trim(), hours.trim()];
     }
     ```
   - ... or it can be done by [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)-ting with a [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) like ... [/(^[^:\s]+)\s*:\s*/](https://regex101.com/r/vGRck7/1) ... and [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)-ing the results array ...

     ```
     function regexSplitOpeningHoursEntry(entry) {
       // [https://regex101.com/r/vGRck7/3]
       // entry.split(':')                 // ["Mon  ", " 9", "00AM - 7", "00PM"]

       // [https://regex101.com/r/vGRck7/2]
       // entry.split(/\s*:\s*/)           // ["Mon", "9", "00AM - 7", "00PM"]

       // [https://regex101.com/r/vGRck7/1]
       // entry.split(/(^[^:\s]+)\s*:\s*/) // ["", "Mon", "9:00AM - 7:00PM"];

       return entry.split(/(^[^:\s]+)\s*:\s*/).slice(1);
     }
     ```
2. Then one has to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) an entire array of opening hours strings into an array of arrays, where each array-item contains the `day` value as first and the `hours` value as second array item ... either like this ...

   ```
   sampleList.map(splitOpeningHoursEntry);
   ```

   ... or like that ...

   ```
   sampleList.map(regexSplitOpeningHoursEntry);
   ```
3. On top one needs to [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) this array of splitted `[<day>, <hours>]` entries into its compact form ...
4. Finally one has to `map` each splitted `[<day>, <hours>]` entry with a [concatenation task](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) back into its human readable string form....

```js
const sampleList = [
  'Mon  : 9:00AM - 7:00PM',
  'Tue  : 9:00AM - 10:00PM',
  'Wed  : Closed',
  'Thu  : 9:00AM - 7:00PM',
  'Fri  : 9:00AM - 7:00PM',
  'Sat  :  Closed',
  'Sun  :  Closed',
];

function splitOpeningHoursEntry(entry) {
  // e.g.: 'Mon  : 9:00AM - 7:00PM'
  const indexOfColon = entry.indexOf(':'); // e.g. 5

  // entry.substring(0, 5) ... e.g.: 'Mon  '
  const day = entry.substring(0, indexOfColon);
  // entry.substring(6) ... e.g.: ' 9:00AM - 7:00PM'
  const hours = entry.substring(indexOfColon + 1);

  // e.g.: ['Mon', '9:00AM - 7:00PM']
  return [day.trim(), hours.trim()];
}
function regexSplitOpeningHoursEntry(entry) {
  // [https://regex101.com/r/vGRck7/3]
  // entry.split(':')                 // ["Mon  ", " 9", "00AM - 7", "00PM"]

  // [https://regex101.com/r/vGRck7/2]
  // entry.split(/\s*:\s*/)           // ["Mon", "9", "00AM - 7", "00PM"]

  // [https://regex101.com/r/vGRck7/1]
  // entry.split(/(^[^:\s]+)\s*:\s*/) // ["", "Mon", "9:00AM - 7:00PM"];

  return entry.split(/(^[^:\s]+)\s*:\s*/).slice(1);
}

function compactOpeningHoursEntries(compactEntries, splitEntry, idx, arr) {
  // get the predecessor item of the currently
  // processed `splitEntry` item or default to [].
  const prevSplitEntry = arr[idx - 1] || [];

  // get the successor item of the currently
  // processed `splitEntry` item or default to [].
  const nextSplitEntry = arr[idx + 1] || [];

  if (prevSplitEntry[1] !== splitEntry[1]) {
    // in case the previous and current `hours` values do not match ...

    // ... push the current entry of splitted `day` and `hours`
    // values into `compactEntries` which is the accumulating
    // array of the compacted form of all opening hours entries.
    compactEntries.push(splitEntry);

  } else if (nextSplitEntry[1] !== splitEntry[1]) {
    // ... or in case the next and current `hours` values do not match ...

    const lastCompactEntry = compactEntries[compactEntries.length - 1];

    // ...retrieve the first and the last day value
    // of a compactly written day-range format...
    const firstDayInRange = lastCompactEntry[0];
    const lastDayInRange = splitEntry[0];

    // ...and create and rewrite its compact form
    // as the compacted entry's final day value.
    lastCompactEntry[0] = firstDayInRange + '-' + lastDayInRange;
  }
  return compactEntries;
}

function concatOpeningHoursEntry([day, hours]) {
  return `${ day }: ${ hours }`;
}

// First one needs to separate the `day` from the
// `hours` part of a single opening hours string
console.log(
  "splitOpeningHoursEntry('Mon  : 9:00AM - 7:00PM') ...",
  splitOpeningHoursEntry('Mon  : 9:00AM - 7:00PM')
);
console.log(
  "regexSplitOpeningHoursEntry('Mon  : 9:00AM - 7:00PM') ...",
  regexSplitOpeningHoursEntry('Mon  : 9:00AM - 7:00PM')
);

// Then one does map an entire array of opening hours strings
// into an array of arrays, where each array item contains the
// `day` value as first and the `hours` value as second array item.
console.log(
  '... list item `split` mapping ... ',
  sampleList
    .map(splitOpeningHoursEntry)
  //.map(regexSplitOpeningHoursEntry)
)

// On top one has to `reduce` this array of splitted
// `[<day>, <hours>]` entries into its compact form.
console.log(
  '... list item `split` mapping and split entry reducing ... ',
  sampleList
    .map(splitOpeningHoursEntry)
    .reduce(compactOpeningHoursEntries, [])
);

// Finally one needs to `map` each splitted `[<day>, <hours>]` entry
// with a concatenation task back into its human readable string form.
console.log(
  '... list item `split` mapping, reducing and a final concatenation mapping ... ',
  sampleList
    .map(splitOpeningHoursEntry)
    .reduce(compactOpeningHoursEntries, [])
    .map(concatOpeningHoursEntry)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Another less talkative proof of concept ...

```js
function splitOpeningHoursEntry(entry) {
  return entry.split(/(^[^:\s]+)\s*:\s*/).slice(1);
}
function concatOpeningHoursEntry([day, hours]) {
  return `${ day }: ${ hours }`;
}

function compactOpeningHoursEntries(compactEntries, splitEntry, idx, arr) {
  const prevSplitEntry = arr[idx - 1] || [];
  const nextSplitEntry = arr[idx + 1] || [];

  if (prevSplitEntry[1] !== splitEntry[1]) {

    compactEntries.push(splitEntry);

  } else if (nextSplitEntry[1] !== splitEntry[1]) {
    const lastCompactEntry = compactEntries[compactEntries.length - 1];

    const firstDayInRange = lastCompactEntry[0];
    const lastDayInRange = splitEntry[0];

    lastCompactEntry[0] = firstDayInRange + '-' + lastDayInRange;
  }
  return compactEntries;
}
console.log([
    'Mon  : 08:00AM - 17:00PM',
    'Tue  : 08:00AM - 17:00PM',
    'Wed  : 08:00AM - 17:00PM',
    'Thu  : 10:00AM - 14:00PM',
    'Fri  : 10:00AM - 14:00PM',
    'Sat  :  Closed',
    'Sun  :  Closed',
  ], '=>', [
    'Mon  : 08:00AM - 17:00PM',
    'Tue  : 08:00AM - 17:00PM',
    'Wed  : 08:00AM - 17:00PM',
    'Thu  : 10:00AM - 14:00PM',
    'Fri  : 10:00AM - 14:00PM',
    'Sat  :  Closed',
    'Sun  :  Closed',
  ]
  .map(splitOpeningHoursEntry)
  .reduce(compactOpeningHoursEntries, [])
  .map(concatOpeningHoursEntry)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```